# How to edit entity and add pagination in Jhipster generated project

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

Already several entities are created. Initially infinite scroll option was selected while creating entities. Now I want to implement pagination instead of infinite scroll. Should I overwrite the entities?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In JHipster, the difference between pagination and infinite scroll are only on the client side. You can regenerate each of your entities, but when Yeoman asks if you want to overwrite preexisting files, press `n` to choose `no` for every file except the AngularJS router, controller, and 'entities' list html. This should allow you to implement pagination with minimal impact.

You can regenerate your entities by changing `"pagination": "infinite-scroll"` to `"pagination": "pagination"` in your entity JSONs under `.jhipster` then re-running `yo jhipster:entity entityName`.

Comment: Coming back to this at a late date, but I have to say this is not entirely true, in the Resource class of the Entity we need to specify that the query is pageable, if not, it will fail to come through, so we also need to alter the WhateverClassResource.java class.  At least in my project I needed to do this in order to apply pagination to a series of entities

Comment: That is true of you had no pagination at all before, but infinite scroll uses pagination on the server side.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks for quick reply! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are following 2 cases,

You can identify your case by observing `"pagination"` option from `EntityName.json` file from `./ProjectName/.jhipster` directory,

**Case 1: "pagination": "infinite-scroll" i.e. existing pagination is available**

In this case, you can regenerate entities with a less impact. Refer @geraldhumphries answer. [How to edit entity and add pagination in Jhipster generated project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509558/how-to-edit-entity-and-add-pagination-in-jhipster-generated-project/37532972#37532972)

**Case 2: "pagination": "no" i.e. existing pagination is not available**

To add pagination to existing entity change `"pagination"` option from `"pagination": "no"` to `"pagination": true` and update entities by using,
`yo jhipster:entity EntityName` or
by importing `jhipster import-jdl jdl.jh`[In case of JDL]

but In this case, the impact will be on both the server and client side.
On the server side mainly `EntityNameResource.java` and `EntityNameService.java` will change.
On the client side EntityName.component.html, multiple supporting.ts files will change.